# Initial load animations for Sveltekit SSR pages?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I've followed the issues in github, and it seems to be a HUGE open-ended question in terms of 1st party support. Has anybody implemented any type of logic to enable transitions on initial page load? Any CodePen examples or whatnot? It's really ugly seeing things pop in the first time.

some sample code:

```
<div class="grid lg:grid-cols-2 justify-between items-center py-[6rem] max-w-[1200px] m-auto">
  <img in:fly={{x: 50, delay: 250, duration: 500}} class="p-5 m-auto hover:scale-[105%] transition-scale duration-150" src="/images/home-responsive-devices.jpeg" alt="Homepage on different devices"/>
  <div in:fade={{delay: 500, duration: 500}} class="flex flex-col w-full">
    <p class="leading-8 px-10 py-6 text-justify"><span class="font-semibold">AdPrompt</span> believes content creators should make more revenue for their work. That is why we are committed to building tools that help people turn passions into professions. Our proprietary A.I. and advertising technologies remove the inefficiencies from today’s digital advertising landscape, passing that value on to real people doing what they love.</p>
    <a class="m-auto" href="/contact"><button class="self-center mt-10 btn btn-primary btn-outline">Learn More</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just spitballing here, but what if you check for `$!navigating` like @carlosV2 suggests, then `goto` with `{replaceState: true}` to a dummy empty page which then does a `goto` back to your desired landing page which could then have animations.

Comment: I can do all of that stuff, but then the SSR page will be blank (If I'm not mistaken the $navigation object is client-side). I can make it work in a few ways, but they all break SSR. I think I found a solution using svelte-motion but I still have more testing to do. If it works, I'll post it here so if anybody else has this issue they can look to that for inspiration. :)

Comment: Did you ever find a sensible solution to this @JoelHager ? This seems like a pretty big oversight imo

Comment: I did not. Not one that didn't come with some drawback or another.

Answer (score 1):

I've built a component that could do what you need:

```html
<script>
  import { fade } from 'svelte/transition';
  import { navigating } from '$app/stores';
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let animate = !$navigating;
  let loaded = false;

  onMount(() => loaded = true);
</script>

{#if animate}
  {#if loaded}
    <div in:fade={{delay: 500, duration: 500}} class="contents">
      <slot/>
    </div>
  {/if}
{:else}
  <slot/>
{/if}
```

The idea behind this component is to trigger the animation only if `$navigating` is `null` (it is `null` for the first load and then it contains an object with the navigation details on subsequent loads) and after the component has been mounted.

You can take a [look at this REPL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-n1eewp?file=src%2Froutes%2FAnimateOnLoad.svelte,src%2Froutes%2F%2Bpage.svelte&terminal=dev).

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it but, at least, it isolated and reusable.

The big pity is that Svelte allows for such animations to happen if you set the [`intro` parameter](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api) in the component to `true` but I haven't found a way to set this from within the component itself.

Comment: Yeah - intro allows it but it disables SSR. That's the big issue. Keeping SSR *with* intro animations. Does this account for it?

Comment: This component does not use intro. With the transitions as Svelte have them, you must not have your component rendered since the transitions trigger precisely when they are rendered so, obviously, if you render the elements during SSR, they won't show the animation. The component I wrote defers the rendering of the component till the client but runs any other SSR code. If this does not work for you, then, perhaps, you will need to build your own animations aside of Svelte's ones.

Comment: Just checked, and unfortunately, this breaks SSR.

Comment: In which way? What exactly breaks? What do you need it to do?

Comment: It breaks SSR. The whole point of SSR is that the initial content is served via the server with no client hydration. With this component, all of the content is only loaded client-side. So it 'works' in the sense that it behaves as one would expect, but no differently than using intro (which would enable the animations to work as well by disabling SSR).

Comment: Right, so this is why I said that if you want this kind of behaviour, you will need to build the animations yourself. For example, delivering the HTML with `display: none` (so that he contents are there but they are not visible) and when the page loads, you apply a custom CSS class that brings the animation you need. I can't see a way of doing it with Svelte transitions.

Comment: I certainly appreciate your help, and I am in no way trying to be combative - it's just that I thought I had explained that in my initial question. I want transitions (or similar) to work with SSR. It seems like such a *huge* missed opportunity to not have this available. It makes them almost useless to a website with SSR.